# odoo 10 scan a barcode and start an action

Tags: javascript, python, odoo

`using odoo 10` In my module I manage my workshop by creating a repair order with a barcode, so  What I want to do is click the button `start_btn` by reading barcode value using a barcode scanner so I can start the timer after scanning my repair order, on my methode `on_barcode_scanned` I've called `toggle_start` the button status did change but the timer didn't start

I have been told that I have to use javascript so I can click the button magically, but I have no idea how to do it, waiting for your help.

thanks in advance, best regard.

```
class project_task(models.Model):
    _name = 'project.task'
    _inherit = ['project.task', 'barcodes.barcode_events_mixin']

    # _barcode_scanned is in the formview
    _barcode_scanned = fields.Char("Barcode Scanned", help="Value of the last barcode scanned.", store=False)

    def on_barcode_scanned(self, barcode):
        self.toggle_start()
```

in my view:

```
            <div name="button_box" position="inside">
                <field name='test_barcode' options="{'barcode_events': 'True'}" widget="field_float_scannable"/>
                <button name="toggle_start" id="start_btn" type="object"
                        class="oe_stat_button" icon="fa-clock-o">
                    <field name="task_timer" widget="boolean_button"
                        options='{"terminology": {
                                "string_true": "Started",
                                "hover_true": "Pause",
                                "string_false": "Timer",
                                "hover_false": "Start"
                            }}'/>
                </button>
            </div>
```

Comment: Hi, I edited your questions, adding odoo-10 tag and improved some formatting, making your question is well asked, easier to be found/answered, but I  don't know why you rolled it back? What am I missing?

Comment: Mr.Imad I do really need your help now!!!@imad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I have found after a deep research in `arodoo_stock_barcode` module, and `project_task_timer` the module you are trying to work with:

- you have to to add in your model `_barcode_scanned`field

  ```
  class project_task(models.Model):
      _name = 'project.task'
      _inherit = ['project.task', 'barcodes.barcode_events_mixin']

      # _barcode_scanned is in the formview
      _barcode_scanned = fields.Char("Barcode Scanned", help="Value of the last barcode scanned.", store=False)
      test_barcode = fields.Char("barcode")
  ```
- don't use `on_barcode_scanned` method: just use a javascript file, so how to do it:

  ```
  odoo.define('project_task_timer.MyScript', function (require) {
  "use strict";
      var core = require('web.core');
      var Model = require('web.Model');
      var flag = false;
      var FormViewBarcodeHandler = require('barcodes.FormViewBarcodeHandler');
  var _t = core._t;
  var MyScript = FormViewBarcodeHandler.extend({

  init: function (parent, context) {
      if (parent.ViewManager.action) {
          this.form_view_initial_mode = parent.ViewManager.action.context.form_view_initial_mode;
      } else if (parent.ViewManager.view_form) {
          this.form_view_initial_mode = parent.ViewManager.view_form.options.initial_mode;
      }
  },
  start: function () {
       });
     },
  pre_onchange_hook: function (barcode) {

      var barcode_filed = this.form_view.datarecord.test_barcode;
      var deferred = $.Deferred();
      if (barcode_filed === barcode) { 
         // to change the stage from new to being serviced              
             $(".o_form_view ul.oe_form_status_clickable li:nth-child(2)").click();
              $(".oe_button_box button:nth-child(3)").click();

          return deferred.reject();
      }
  },

  open_wizard: function (action) {
      var self = this;
      this.form_view.trigger('detached');
      this.do_action(action, {
          on_close: function () {
              self.form_view.trigger('attached');
              self.form_view.reload();
          }
      });
  }
  });
       core.form_widget_registry.add('myscript', MyScript);
       return MyScript;
  });
  ```

ps: if you want to add `on_barcode_scanned` methode to your inherited model you can do it, but you can't click a button using python.

good luck.